# I'm using OC4J 10.1.3.5.0 and i have an exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, oc4j

I'm using OC4J 10.1.3.5.0 and there is a problem with jpa 2. I put hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar in the class path. When deploy my app and use @OneToMany annotation in my code, I get this exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:javax.persistence.OneToMany.orphanRemoval()Z

When i remove it from code, my app runs normally.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: i don't know the problem these is the first time i use oc4j

Comment: The title of this question makes me smile.

Comment: How are you getting it in the classpath?  You might try using the applib folder.

Comment: that is very fun exception :)

Comment: i put it in the applib and in the app files and no change

Comment: What other dependencies do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OC4J_PATH\j2ee\home\lib\persistance.jar
this jar file jpa 1 and loaded with server start
i replaced this jar with Jpa 2 jar with the same name
and my app run normally

Answer (score 1):

You have incompatible JPA library in the classpath. The error "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError" says there is no method "orphanRemoval()" in class "javax.persistence.OneToMany". You should be able to check the library version based on the stack trace.

Check the class in OC4J deployed war file directory. Also make sure there are no conflicting libraries in the OC4J container lib directory (they would take precedence over your packaged jars).

Comment: these exception occurs only when i use OneToMany Annotation and when i use ManyToOne no exception occurs

Comment: But it surely has incompatible libraries in the classpath (NoSuchMethodError), try debugging into the hibernate libraries and check if its picking the correct jar.
Have you looked @ 
1) http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?94720-NoSuchMethodError-javax-persistence-OneToMany-orphanRemoval()Z
2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189056/hibernate-3-5-x-nosuchmethoderror-javax-persistence-onetomany-orphanremoval
3) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591684/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-persistence-onetomany-orphanremovalz