# Hibernate mapping exception: Could not determine type for columns

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I want to do a mapping between my two classes Customer and CustomerGroup and i am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: studyproject.CustomerGroup, at table: CUSTOMER, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(assignedTo)]
```

my CustomerGroup Class is: (fyi: at the beginning i don't need the BonusPackage type, therefore i didn't annotate it)

```
package studyproject;


import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Id;


public class CustomerGroup {
private String name;
private String description;
private int id;
private BonusPackage bonusPackage;

public CustomerGroup(int id,String name, String description,
        BonusPackage bonusPackage) {
    super();
    this.id=id;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.bonusPackage = bonusPackage;
}

@Column(name="id")
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name="name")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Column(name="description")
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
@Transient
public BonusPackage getBonusPackage() {
    return bonusPackage;
}

public void setBonusPackage(BonusPackage bonusPackage) {
    this.bonusPackage = bonusPackage;
}
@Transient
public boolean generateServiceMails() {
    return false;
}
```

the customer class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CUSTOMER")

public class Customer {
private int id;
private String forename;
private String surname;
private char gender;
private Date birthday;
private double generatedProfitsTotal;
private double generatedProfitsLastYear;    
private CustomerGroup assignedTo;

public Customer(int id, String forename, String surname, char gender,
        Date birthday) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.forename = forename;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.birthday = birthday;
}

@Id
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "forename")
public String getForename() {
    return forename;
}

public void setForename(String forename) {
    this.forename = forename;
}
@Column(name = "surename")
public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}
@Column(name = "gender")
public char getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(char gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}
@Column(name = "birthday")
public Date getBirthday() {
    return birthday;
}

public void setBirthday(Date birthday) {
    this.birthday = birthday;
}
@Column(name = "generatedProfitsTotal")
public double getGeneratedProfitsTotal() {
    return generatedProfitsTotal;
}

public void setGeneratedProfitsTotal(double generatedProfitsTotal) {
    this.generatedProfitsTotal = generatedProfitsTotal;
}
@Column(name = "generatedProfitsLastYear")
public double getGeneratedProfitsLastYear() {
    return generatedProfitsLastYear;
}

public void setGeneratedProfitsLastYear(double generatedProfitsLastYear) {
    this.generatedProfitsLastYear = generatedProfitsLastYear;
}


@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "id", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public CustomerGroup getAssignedTo() {
    return assignedTo;
}

public void setAssignedTo(CustomerGroup assignedTo) {
    this.assignedTo = assignedTo;
}
```

The method that commits the transaction:

```
public String saveAllDataORM(){

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
        applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();


        for(Customer c:this.getCustomers()) {
            session.persist(c);

        }
    transaction.commit();
            session.close();

        return "Done";
    }
```

my customer.hbm.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd" >
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="studyproject.Customer"
 table="CUSTOMER">
 <id name="id" type="int">
 <column name="ID"/>
 <generator class="assigned"/>
 </id>

 <property name="forename" type="java.lang.String">
 <column name="FORENAME"/>
 </property>

  <property name="surname" type="java.lang.String">
 <column name="SURNAME"/>
 </property>

 <property name="gender" type="java.lang.Character">
 <column name="GENDER"/>
 </property>

  <property name="birthday" type="java.util.Date">
 <column name="birthday"/>
 </property>

 property name="generatedProfitsTotal" type="java.lang.Double">
 <column name="generatedProfitsTotal"/>
 </property>

 <property name="generatedProfitsLastYear" type="java.lang.Double">
 <column name="generatedProfitsLastYear"/>
 </property>

 <property name = "assignedTo" type ="studyproject.CustomerGroup">
            <column name="assignedTo" />

 </property>



 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I checked several FAQs and other Threads here at stackoverflow, mostly there was problems with annotations. I tried to fix it in my code but i can't accomplish.. :/

for better illustration i have an UML here: [image: UML]

Comment: Why are you mixing annotation mapping and xml mapping, you can mark properties as @Transient if you do not want to map them.

Comment: actually i tried to use hibernate before without trying to map the type "customerGroup". Then after i extended to "Customergroup" type - it didn't work, so then i tried to map them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming class `CustomerGroup` reprsents `CustomerGroup` table in database, add below mentioned annotations:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CustomerGroup")
public class CustomerGroup
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. Maybe the error is in the Customer.hbm.xml? The mapping could have an error.

Comment: You are mixing xml-mapping and annotations here. Annotations alone are enough in you case. First remove `customer.hbm.xml` from hibernate configuration file.

Comment: Ok, i deleted all the xml mapping sources in hibernate.cfg.xml. Now getting an other error: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: studyproject.Customer

Comment: Add `<mapping class="studyproject.Customer"/>` in your hibernate configuration fiile.

Comment: Ok, next error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.OneToOne.orphanRemoval()Z . I have looked a little bit on stackoverflow, and it seems that it has to do with ejb3-persistence.jar that i have added to my class library. Unfortunately, if i don't import javax.persistence*.*, but import hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.jar (import org.hibernate.annotations.*)  then my annotations(for example @Column) doesnt work.

Comment: Have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189056/hibernate-3-5-x-nosuchmethoderror-javax-persistence-onetomany-orphanremoval

Comment: Thank you i solved the problem, what i am moment struggling is the Relationship between CustomerGroup.class and Customer.class. I changed the Relationship from OneToOne in the Customer.class to manyToOne. I updated the classes in the starting post. Getting now a different error:  com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`hibernatetesting`.`customer`, CONSTRAINT `FK_k7730vgdxnwf8go0vh8a5fq9l` FOREIGN KEY (`assignedTo_id`) REFERENCES `customergroup` (`id`))

Comment: Shouldi open a new question, because apparently i solved the question in the starting topic...?

Comment: Ideally you should :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82509/discussion-between-arpit-and-facebookude).

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell Hibernate which kind of association you want between `Customer` and `CustomerGroup`: one-to-one, or many-to-one.

Also, by default, all properties are mapped by JPA standard (that's why Hibernate has to adhere to it if you use JPA annotations).

If you want to make a property transient, you have to explicitly do it:

```
@Transient
public BonusPackage getBonusPackage() {
    return bonusPackage;
}
```

Comment: Still having the same error message: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: studyproject.CustomerGroup, at table: CUSTOMER, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(assignedTo)]

Comment: Please see my edited answer. Sorry, I didn't see the actual error at first. Nevertheless, the remark for `@Transient` still aplies.

Comment: Do i understand that correctly that for @OneToOne association i need a foreign key? That is not the case. To illustrate my environment i have uploaded an UML here: http://fs2.directupload.net/images/150705/2fahgyk2.jpg Normally the CustomerGroup is added with a method in the customer class. (this.customerGroups.add(new CustomerGroup(......));

Comment: So, how do you know which customer group a customer belongs to?

Comment: getAssignetTo() method delivers a customerGroup.

Comment: I didn't mean that. How do you know it in the database?

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake in my 2nd previous comment. Instead of: "Normally the CustomerGroup is added with a method in the customer class. (this.customerGroups.add(new CustomerGroup(......));" i meant: Normally the CustomerGroup is added with a method in the main class. (this.customerGroups.add(new CustomerGroup(......)); -> So Customer Groups is filled in the main class. To your question: There is not a linking to a database, in the main class i have a method that assigns a CustomerGroup to a Customer with a logic. After they are assigned, i want to make the Customer Class persistent.

Comment: Ok, in that case make `getAssignedTo` transient as well, so that it is ignored by JPA, and remove @Column mapping from it.

Comment: Ok that would lead me to the start (i could save the Customer Class without getAssignedTo defined in the Customer.hbm.xml file). To sum up: without defining a proper database schema for CustomerGroups with a Key, i can't refer from Customer Class to the CustomerGroup class? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you can't save something into nothing. How could Hibernate know to reconstruct the object graph when it loads data from database (how could it know which group a customer belongs to if you didn't store that information somewhere)? Regarding the keys, if it really is a one-to-one relationship, you can choose any of the two tables to add the foreign key to, or you can use `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` if the two tables share the same primary key value for the associated entity instances.

Comment: You know the design better, but I don't think that a customer group is allowed to contain only one customer (or at best you are using a non-intuitive naming convention).

Comment: Thanks to all your comments, i changed the design of the CustomerGroup. I have added setters and getters, and i try to join with a OneToOne Relationship (see Customer.class in the starting post, i have updated it). But still getting the same error: Could not determine type for: studyproject.CustomerGroup, at table: CUSTOMER, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(assignedTo)]