# can't create entity manager, when add relationships

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager, one-to-one

My classes:

```
@Entity
public class Contacts {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String login;
    private long token;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private UserInfo user;
//constructors, getters...
}
@Entity(name = "user_info")
public class UserInfo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Contacts contact;
}
```

I get this error:java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.OneToOne.orphanRemoval()Z

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189056/hibernate-3-5-x-nosuchmethoderror-javax-persistence-onetomany-orphanremoval

Comment: You just need to remove (or replace)  an old jar with `@OneToOne` annotation as @Ramanlfc suggested. `orphanRemoval()` was added in  Java Persistence 2.0.

Comment: thanks you, it's helped