# war package not working on wasce 2.1.1.6 while working on wasce 3.0.0.3

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I am trying to deploy war on wasce 2.1.1.6 and it is getting failed at deployment with below error :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path
>   resource [applicationContext-force.xml]: Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.persistence.OneToMany.orphanRemoval()Z

While the same package is working fine on wasce 3.0.0.3. Due to some constraint we can't use 3.0.0.3
 attaching pom

```
<properties>
        <spring.version>4.2.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.security.version>4.1.0.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <poi.version>3.8</poi.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-contrib</artifactId>
            <version>3.5-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-examples</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-excelant</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.flex</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-flex</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bowstreet</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.5.2.LO75347</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ant-contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-contrib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0b3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>avalon-framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>avalon-framework</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>backport-util-concurrent</groupId>
            <artifactId>backport-util-concurrent</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>batik-ext</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>batik</groupId>
            <artifactId>batik-1.5-fop</artifactId>
            <version>0.20-5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.beanshell</groupId>
            <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
            <version>2.0b5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.blazeds</groupId>
            <artifactId>cfgatewayadapter</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.blazeds</groupId>
            <artifactId>blazeds-common</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.14931</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.blazeds</groupId>
            <artifactId>blazeds-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.14931</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.blazeds</groupId>
            <artifactId>blazeds-opt</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.3978</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.blazeds</groupId>
            <artifactId>blazeds-proxy</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.14931</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.blazeds</groupId>
            <artifactId>blazeds-remoting</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.14931</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>httpcore</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.jacoco.ant</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.6.201602180812</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            <version>6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.naming</groupId>
            <artifactId>jndi</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.53</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.javaee</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>6.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jscape.inet</groupId>
            <artifactId>sftp</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar-plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-ant-task</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>weblogic</groupId>
            <artifactId>weblogic</artifactId>
            <version>9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.internal.35503.acctapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>4.2_C0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>bsf</groupId>
            <artifactId>bsf</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ojdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.netegrity</groupId>
            <artifactId>smjavaagentapi</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspose.cells</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json_simple_163094</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
          <version>1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.livesense</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.liveSense.scripting.jsp.taglib.jsonatg</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>a_MW</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>*.xml</include>
                                <include>*.xsd</include>
                                <include>*.png</include>
                                <include>*.sh</include>
                                <include>*.properties</include>
                            </includes>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*</include>
                            </includes>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                    <packagingExcludes>
                        WEB-INF/lib/weblogic-*.jar,
                        WEB-INF/lib/cglib-*.jar,
                        **/.svn
                    </packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you show your pom? Related question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189056/hibernate-3-5-x-nosuchmethoderror-javax-persistence-onetomany-orphanremoval

Comment: adding pom file for your reference. @I-LOVE-2-REVIVE